# Simulating a click on a React Element

Tags: html, reactjs, events, mouseevent

I'm using React with Leaflet, and want to launch the drawing menu immediately upon the component mounting, without making the user click any buttons. The React Leaflet Draw API is a bit opaque on this, and what I'd like to do to make this simple is to trigger a click on the appropriate button programmatically, without the user having to. I'll then hide the button.

The trouble is that I'm not having any luck either using the .click() or the MouseEvent('click') APIs. Here's my attempt at the latter:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../../actions';
import { Polygon, FeatureGroup } from 'react-leaflet';
import { EditControl } from 'react-leaflet-draw';

export class DrawNewPlot extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let simulateClick = elem => {
            let evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
                bubbles: true,
                view: window
            });
        };
        let drawControl = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-draw-toolbar');
        simulateClick(drawControl);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <FeatureGroup>
                <EditControl
                    position="bottomright"
                    onEdited={e => {
                        e.layers.eachLayer(a => {
                            this.props.setNewPlotGeojson(a.toGeoJSON());
                        });
                    }}
                    onCreated={e => {
                        this.props.setNewPlotGeojson(e.layer.toGeoJSON());
                    }}
                    draw={{
                        marker: false,
                        circle: false,
                        rectangle: false,
                        polygon: true,
                        polyline: false,
                        circlemarker: false,
                        edit: false
                    }}
                    edit={{ edit: false }}
                />
            </FeatureGroup>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        addingNewPlotDetails: state.plots.addingNewPlotDetails
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(DrawNewPlot);
```

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your simulateClick method creates the event, but never dispatches it. Try adding `elem.dispatchEvent(evt);`

Although I must add that simulating mouse click this way just to trigger some initial side effect feels wrong. I am not familiar with Leaflet, but it could be worth checking if they have some API to set initial state

Comment: Another issue i noticed in your code above, getElementsByClassName returns an array, not a single element, try logging out and see if that classname matches with only 1 element, if so, you shoud also add [0] at the end, i.e. document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-draw-toolbar')[0];